# How to obtain HTML code of a specific URL?

Tags: parsing, curl, web-scraping, firebug

I'm trying to parse a URL, but I can't obtain the HTML code with Firebug. The URL has a previous verification with postal code, but when I'm trying to add the parameters in my curl/wget call, it doesn't work.

The URL is:

```
https://www.alimentacion.alcampo.es/tienda/home.php
```

I'm trying to get data accessing it with:

```
https://www.alimentacion.alcampo.es/tienda/home.php?warehouse=0&cp=28030
```

Comment: If you only want to get the HTML code, why don't you copy it from within Firebug's *HTML* panel?

Comment: Well my idea is make calls with curl periodically over website